# Is possible using std function on header, using boost function on implement ?

Tags: c++, boost, std

I'm developing a c++ project of API, it needs to allow user set functions for callback,

able to passing class member function as callback,

it's easy to implement with boost function/bind,

but I don't want to include boost for user,

so is possible using std function on header, then using boost function on implement?

I just try a simple test, it works, but is this way safety ? any risks ? any better ways ?

```
class A {

public:

void test();

void methodA (int size); // std::cout << "size: " << size << std::endl;

std::function<void ()> myCallback;

}

A::test()
{
myCallback = boost::bind(&A::methodA, this, 30);

myCallback(); //print size: 30
}
```

Comment: It should work. But why don't you use `std::function` in the implementation?

Comment: I'm an iOS Developer actually, my workmate said that boost is better for cross-platforms, this library will using on Win, iOS, MAC, Android

Comment: But the clients will need `std::function` anyway, for the header.

Comment: std is more easier to get for client?
I can build directly from Xcode, VS 2012

Comment: It is, since std::function accepts a functor (any type T with operator() overloaded) as argument.

Comment: is this a good way? I do it because I can't set a member function as callback directly, would like to know more ways in this case, I have few experience with c++

Comment: If your client needs the header that has the `A` class definition, then your client *needs* C++11 std lib anyway.

Comment: thanks for helping :), my final solution, is using static function with class instance to solve member function as callback issue.